# Does Doodle Jump use UIKit or OpenGL ES

Tags: iphone, uikit, opengl-es

looking at the iPhone app Doodle Jump I am not quite sure what kind of technologie Lima Sky used to draw the graphics. Is it UIKit, CoreAnimation, OpenGL ES or a combination. All Some hint for UIKit or some sort of combination is the theme selector at the bottom of the main menu, which acts like some kind of a UIControl.

Somebody has an idea?

Thx, Kie

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure it is OpenGL ES. Like Horace said, they have said so in an interview. I didn't think their statement meant "Core Graphics which is backed by OpenGL," I think it meant what it said, which is simply "OpenGL." (ES). It makes sense, if only because Apple's documentation recommends OpenGL ES for game graphics. It's a fairly simple game, but there is still a lot going on (for example, a thread looking up scores on a remote server, an algorithm to select upcoming terrain, collision detection with platforms and monsters and nose balls) and as a developer you would want direct control over the graphics rendering at the lowest reasonable level. Also, ES is just as usable for 2D graphics as for 3D, so assuming a 2D game uses Quartz just because it is 2D is silly.

Answer (score 1):

According to an [interview](http://www.pocketgamer.biz/r/PG.Biz/Doodle+Jump/feature.asp?c=15412), it's OpenGL.

Comment: Yeah I read this interview too, but the whole iPhone UI bases on OpenGL calls in the background. I think they talking about this.

Comment: No - they're talking about iPhone 3G vs 3GS. There's no way that they'd make the entire UI slower going from 3G to 3GS. I would bet on different optimized pixel formats and texture sizes.

Answer (score -1):

As it's only 2D drawing I suppose they mainly used Quartz for drawing with some UIKit components and Core Animation.